# selective averaging of dataframe entries depending on labels

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
    ID   KD     DT   
0    4    2     5.6  
1    4    5     8.7  
4    4    8     1.9  
5    4    9     1.7  
6    4    1     8.8    
3    4    3     7.2  
9    4    4     3.1
```

I also have an array of labels, same size as the total number of unique `KD`

`L = [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]` which simply indicates that `KD == 1` is associated with label `0` `KD == 2` with label `0 ... KD == 9` with label `1` etc. (`L` is stored for the sorted order of `KD`).

Now I have a two lists, `l1 = [1,2,5,9]` and `l2 = [3,4,8]`. I want to set the value of `DT` corresponding to the `KD` values in `l2` such that it is the average of the `DT` values in `l1` if both have the same labels.

In the example,  `KD == 3` as the same label (label = 0) as `KD = 1 and 2` in `l1`. So we set `DT =  (8.8 + 5.6)/2 = 7.2`.

I am now doing this using a for loop, by iterating over `l2` and finding the `l1` entries which has the same labels and then averaging.  Is there a way that I can do this very efficiently, by getting rid of the for loop ?

My output can be a dictionary of the form
`d = {3:7.2, 4: 5.2, 8: 5.2}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, first set_index the KD column, then you can select 'DT' and with `where` replace values that are not `isin(l1)` with Nan. then you `groupby.transform` the `map` of the column KD with their group number in `L` and get the `mean`. Finally `loc` only the KD that are `isin(l2)` and use `to_dict` to get your expected output

```
df_ = df.set_index('KD')
print ( df_['DT'].where(df_.index.isin(l1))\
                .groupby(df_.index.map(pd.Series(L, df_.index.sort_values())))\
                .transform('mean')\
                .loc[df_.index.isin(l2)]\
                .to_dict()
      )
{8: 5.199999999999999, 3: 7.2, 4: 5.199999999999999}
```

Comment: the key values are not corresponding `KD` values